# azure db responds too long

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using azure mobile services. I did custom API and I was trying to retrieve around 70 000 records from the table within it. My request to API was coming back with an error 503 (request time out). I tried to decrease number of requests up to 50 000 and the request time took approximately 25 sec. I did not try to get my 50 000 records through http protocol. I was only trying to retrieve records amount.

```
exports.register = function(app) {
    app.get("/", getById);
};


function getById(request, response) {
    var occupancyrecord = request.service.tables.getTable('occupancyrecord').take(50000);

    occupancyrecord.read({
        success: function(items){
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, [items.length])
        }
    });
}
```

How can I increase number of records I would like to receive? 50 000 is not what I need. I want 70 000 – 100 000.
And how can I decrease the waiting time from 25 sec to 2-5 or less? 25 sec it too long.

As an example, MySQL local database responds 50 000 records in a period of less than 1 millisecond.

And this is the interaction within the Azure, between DB and custom API...

Answer (score 1):

If you think the DB is the bottleneck you should check if you have the appropriate indexes on the tables that you are querying. Missing indexes can increase response times significantly. The below link can get you started.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345417(v=sql.105).aspx